# LSTM Forecasting Model loss different each run

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am very confused to how this is posibble each run my model loss give different result,
this is my model :

```
model=Sequential()
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(50), input_shape=(time_step, 1)))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu"))
    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')
    model.summary()

    history = model.fit(X_trainSST, y_trainSST, 
            validation_data=(X_testSST,y_testSST),
            epochs=100, batch_size=256,verbose=0)
```

I set neuron to 50 and epoch to 200 my Model Loss plot look good it show no indication of overfitting or underfiting even at very low epoch so i lower my epoch to 100 to make the runtime faster

[result of 200 epoch model loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbPt1.png)

then it  show sign of underfiting...

[result of 100 epoch model loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VkIU.png)

I run it again it still show sign of underfiting then I restart my kernel now it perfect

[100 epoch after kernel restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pfht.png)

I already set random seed using this code

```
tf.random.set_seed(1234)
```